# Standard for defining functions in controller - angular

Tags: angularjs

I am following an article where a controller is like:

```
app.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService) {    
    loadRecords(); 
    function loadRecords(){
      //some code
    }
    $scope.save = function(){
     //some other code
    }
});
```

There is a difference in which loadRecords & save are defined. I prefer all the functions to be written as `$scope.functionName = function()`, for consistency. Will this be right or is there any standard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example which you are showing automatically runs loadRecords() whenever the controller is instantiated , maybe the loadRecords function loads the records from someplace and assigns it to a $scope variable or does some initial functionality which needs to be run whenever an instance of controller is created.

Now, as far as $scope.functionName is concerned, it is used if you want to expose the functionName to the view , i.e, you want to invoke this function from the view(by any event handler ) .

If you dont want to expose the function to the view, then you can write functions as loadRecords() is written (and the author of the article was doing that only )

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see that loadRecords()  is invoked from controller itself and we  cannot call this function from outside.
The another function save() is defined to call from the angular DOM (like by ng-click,ng-change etc..)

if you want to invoke a function from controller itself no need write function like

```
function loadRecords(){
      //some code
    }
```

Comment: you said, `no need write function like`. Then the could should be `$scope.loadRecords() = function()`. Right??

Comment: $scope.loadRecords = function()